# GraphQL query filtering with Strapi V4 and Gatbsy

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, strapi

Since Strapi changed to its never V4 structure it has broken my V3 query which I was using to create pages based on the data returned from Strapi.

The code in my Gatsby-node.js file using the createPages feature is like so:

```
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allStrapiArticles {
        edges {
          node {
            data {
              id
              attributes {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.allStrapiArticles.edges[0].node.data.forEach(article => {
    createPage({
      path: `/blog/${article.attributes.title.replace(" ", "_")}`,
      component: path.resolve(`src/templates/blog/index.js`),
      context: {
        id: article.id,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Then in the page template I use the following query where I reference the id passed in as context:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query ($id: String!) {
    strapiArticles(id: { eq: $id }) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          author
          body
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This seems to return a value of undefined however.

Is anyone familiar with how this query must be altered to conform to Strapi's new structure?

Basically I am trying to access the title, author, and body attributes based upon the object id passed in as context from Gatsby-node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no version available/compatible for Strapi v4 plugin ([`gatsby-source-strapi`](https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi)) yet, as you can see in the repository:

> ⚠️ This version of `gatsby-source-strapi` is only compatible with Strapi
> v3 at the moment. We are currently working on a v4 compatible version.

That said, in the meantime, your only chance is to roll back to v3 and wait for a compatible plugin version (if that's an option).

Comment: That is annoying! But thank you for the help.

Is there a particular command for performing the rollback? Changing the package versions and running yarn only allows me to switch to other v4.0.x versions, and it seems the file structure that V4 creates is not compatible with V3.

EDIT: I tried wiping the straps project folder and creating a new one however it automatically defaults to the v4. Is there a way to append the strapi version to the strap create command?

Comment: You can try using this fork: https://github.com/relate-app/gatsby-source-strapi I haven't use it  but it seems to work fairly well